# Ability to add exception to RKE2 securitypolicy for root pods or specific namespace

Tags: kubernetes, security-policy, rke2

Good afternoon.

So I have an RKE2 cluster with the security policy in place that does not allow root pods to run. I have a pod that has to run as root and have been trying to figure out how to allow my pod to deploy on this cluster without success.

So far I have tried to explicitly set the following:

```
securityContext:
  runAsUser: 0
  runAsGroup: 0
```

The pod still fails to be allowed to run on the environment. Is there a way to not totally disable the security policy and perhaps an an exception for a single namespace? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a pod that has to run as root when cluster with the security policy in place that does not allow root pods to run you need to create a security policy for each namespace. Role Based Access Control (RBAC) allows you to create fine-grained roles and policies to manage access control for users and software running on your cluster, you can find more information in this [document](https://docs.giantswarm.io/getting-started/rbac-and-psp/).
PodSecurityPolicy is deprecated and will be completely removed in v1.25, you should start considering [migrating to Pod Security Admission](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/04/06/podsecuritypolicy-deprecation-past-present-and-future/) where "kube-system" namespace is explicitly exempted from PodSecurity.

Known limitations: [Namespace policy update warnings](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/master/keps/sig-auth/2579-psp-replacement/README.md#namespace-policy-update-warnings)

Follow this [document](https://capstonec.com/2020/04/22/hands-on-with-kubernetes-pod-security-policies/) for more information